# sbt run command after tests

Tags: scala, gulp, sbt

I want to automatically run `gulp` command when `sbt test` command is being executed.

To do this I added the following code to my `build.sbt` file:

```
lazy val cleanWebAssetsTask = TaskKey[Unit]("cleanWebAssets", "Clean web assets with gulp")
cleanWebAssetsTask := {
  "gulp --cwd rest_project clean" !
}

lazy val buildWebAssetsTask = TaskKey[Unit]("buildWebAssets", "Build web assets with gulp")
buildWebAssetsTask := {
  "gulp --cwd rest_project build" !
}

lazy val testWebAssetsTask = TaskKey[Unit]("testWebAssets", "Run JavaScript tests with gulp")
testWebAssetsTask := {
  "gulp --cwd rest_project test" !
}


// This does not work 
test <<= test dependsOn testWebAssetsTask

// This works fine
clean <<= clean dependsOn cleanWebAssetsTask
dist <<= dist dependsOn buildWebAssetsTask
```

But I receive the following error:
Reference to undefined setting:

```
  rest_project/*:test from rest_project/*:test (/Users/ivanmushketyk/Development/project/rest_project-rest/build.sbt:41)
     Did you mean rest_project/web-assets-test:test ?

    at sbt.Init$class.Uninitialized(Settings.scala:270)
    at sbt.Def$.Uninitialized(Def.scala:10)
    at sbt.Init$class.delegate(Settings.scala:191)
    at sbt.Def$.delegate(Def.scala:10)
    at sbt.Init$class.compiled(Settings.scala:138)
    at sbt.Def$.compiled(Def.scala:10)
    at sbt.Init$class.make(Settings.scala:144)
    at sbt.Def$.make(Def.scala:10)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$8.apply(Load.scala:161)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$8.apply(Load.scala:156)
    at sbt.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1025)
    at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:156)
    at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:39)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:548)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:548)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:540)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:540)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:59)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:59)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:93)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.doX$1(State.scala:183)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:190)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:89)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:68)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:63)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:63)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:46)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:30)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:22)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:109)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:38)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] Reference to undefined setting:
[error]
[error]   rest_project/*:test from rest_project/*:test (/Users/ivanmushketyk/Development/project/rest_project/build.sbt:41)
[error]      Did you mean rest_project/web-assets-test:test ?
```

Does it imply that I need to use `rest_project/web-assets-test:test` task? If so, how to access it?